# Laravel Eloquent order posts by created_at and keep sticky post on Top

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Need a help with fetching posts from database and sort them according to **created_at** column but keep **sticky post** (Like in wordpress post system) at the top of order.

***Sticky post is where sticky_post column is true*** in post database

```
public function index(PostFilter $filter)
{
    return Post::with(['author', 'category', 'tags'])
        ->withTrashed()
        ->filter($filter)
        ->paginate(request()->perPage ? request()->perPage : 15);
}
```

Post Schema is as follows:

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('body')->nullable();
        $table->text('excerpt')->nullable();
        $table->string('category_slug');
        $table->boolean('sticky_post')->default(false);
        $table->dateTime('publish_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();

        $table->unsignedInteger('featured_image_id')->nullable();

        $table->unsignedInteger('author_id');
        $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
```

Thank for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`orderBy()` is what you're looking for:

```
public function index(PostFilter $filter)
{
    return Post::with(['author', 'category', 'tags'])
        ->withTrashed()
        ->filter($filter)
        ->orderBy('sticky_post', 'DESC')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->paginate(request()->perPage ? request()->perPage : 15);
}
```

A `true` is represented by a `1` (`TINYINT(1)`) in the database, so all sticky posts will be sorted in a descending order. And any records with same `sticky_post` value will be sorted by the `created_at` column.

All sticky posts will appear at the top (newest first), and non-sticky posts will appear below the sticky posts (newest first).